# Deleting locked files with Java?

Tags: java, filesystems, unlock

We have to delete some directories and their contents using Java running on Windows.

I was worried about running into the directory files being locked.

We could just invoke [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/) to do the delete.  Or is there a more Java centric way to handle this situation?

Comment: Was there any Java code responsible for creating those directories and files before?

Comment: Some of the files, yes.  And some, no.  All the files will have been created days or weeks prior to attempting the delete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java has a very simplistic access to the file system. You can't do this without using some native libraries.